# How can I add an id to a paragraph element in a .before function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I add an id to the P element in this bit of jQuery?

```
$( ".inner" ).before( "<p>Test</p>" );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why make it complicated ?

```
$(".inner").before("<p id='myid'>Test</p>");
```

or

```
$("#a").before($("<p>Test</p>").attr('id', 'myid'));
```

Comment: Wow Im a moron haha. I was putting $(".inner").before("<p id="myid">Test</p>"); I guess the " doesnt work. Thanks :D

Comment: @YeahMKD yup, mixing quotes was the problem ;)

Comment: So Im assuming you only wanna use ' in js?

Comment: @YeahMKD no, you could perfectly write `'<p id="myid">Test</p>'` just don't close at the "bad moment".

Comment: @YeahMKD you can also escape the quotes: `$(".inner").before("<p id=\"myid\">Test</p>")`

Answer (score 0):

You can with this:

```
$(".inner").before("<p id='myId'>Test</p>");
```

This is another way

```
$(".inner").before($("<p>Test</p>", {id: "myId"}));
```

Also

```
$(".inner").before($("<p>Test</p>").attr(id, "myId"));
```

Just to list a few.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it:

```
var p = $( "<p />" ).text( 'Test' ).attr( 'id', 'identifier' );
$( ".inner" ).before( p );
```

Or slightly more simply:

```
$( "<p />" ).text( 'Test' )
            .attr( 'id', 'identifier' )
            .insertBefore( '.inner' );
```

Or you can just add it to the HTML string used to create the paragraph element:

```
$( ".inner" ).before( "<p id='identifier'>Test</p>" );
```